# Why does screeps.com require access to code in public and private repos during sign-in via github?

Tags: github, registration, screeps

Screeps.com allow to sign-in using github account, however it requests permissions which seem to be too high: full access to both public and private repos (code, issues, pull requests and so on). What is the purpose of it? Is it possible to sign-in with github account but disallow access to private repos? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This authentication issue has been fixed already.

Comment: I noticed that also when I signed up about 2 weeks ago. regression? aggression?